# SQL Server match and count on substring

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and have a table like this:

```
ID   Record 
 1   IA12345
 2   IA33333
 3   IA33333
 4   IA44444
 5   MO12345
```

I am trying to put together some SQL to return the two rows that contain IA12345 and MO12345.  So, I need to match on the partial string of the column "Record".  What is complicating my SQL is that I don't want to return matches like IA33333 and IA33333.  Clear as mud?

I am getting twisted up in substrings, group by, count and the like!

Comment: please be more specific. Do you need records that end in 12345 or records that have 12345 in them?

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/

Comment: Yeah, I realize by the answers I should have been much clearer that the "like" portion of my question was important.  I know how the find 12345.  What I am not getting to work is the general idea of looking for a partial match of a column.

Comment: Define "partial match".

Comment: 12345 is just a data value.  Not THE data value I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, Record FROM Table WHERE Record LIKE '%12345'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
from MyTable
where Record like '%12345%'
```

Comment: I think the wildcard at the end is superfluous.

Comment: It's possible that it is not needed.  The original question is not clear as to whether he is looking for 12345 anywhere in the string or only at the end.  I'm not assuming that his example is all the possible data

Answer (score 0):

This will find repeating and/or runs.  For example 333 or 123 or 321

Think of it as Rummy 500

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Record varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
( 1,'IA12345'),
( 2,'IA33333'),
( 3,'IA33333'),
( 4,'IA44444'),
( 5,'MO12345'),
( 6,'M785256')    -- Will be excluded because there is no pattern


Declare @Num table (Num int);Insert Into @Num values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)

Select Distinct A.*
  From @YourTable A
  Join (
        Select Patt=replicate(Num,3) from @Num
        Union All
        Select Patt=right('000'+cast((Num*100+Num*10+Num)+12 as varchar(5)),3) from @Num where Num<8
        Union All
        Select Patt=reverse(right('000'+cast((Num*100+Num*10+Num)+12 as varchar(5)),3)) from @Num where Num<8
       ) B on CharIndex(Patt,Record)>0
```

Returns

```
ID  Record
1   IA12345
2   IA33333
3   IA33333
4   IA44444
5   MO12345
```

> **EDIT**

I should add that runs of 3 is too small, it is a small matter tweak the sub-queries so 333 becomes 3333 and 123 becomes 1234